# My GLSL vertex shader does not produce a triangle primitive

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, opengl-4

Here is the shader source:

```
#version 430 core
void main(void){
    const vec4 vertices[3] = vec4[3](
    vec4(0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0), 
    vec4(-0.25, -0.25, 0.5, 1.0), 
    vec4( 0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0));
    gl_Position = vertices[gl_VertexID]; 
}
```

and here is the function that calls the shader:

```
void render(){
    glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    glUseProgram(myprogram);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
}
```

I can't seem to get a triangle to render on the screen.  Individual points will render if I replace GL_TRIANGLES with GL_POINTS, use 1 input and set gl_position equal to vec4(0.25, 0.25, 0.5, 1.0).  I've tested on other machines to make sure this wasn't an implementation issue.  Any help?

Comment: Did your other machines all have a different GPU vendor? Rendering without any vertex attributes is technically supported, but the example in the OpenGL SuperBible that uses it does not even work on all drivers. From the sounds of things the one thing that's different between your two attempts is that you index your array with `gl_VertexID` in the triangle shader and just set `gl_Position` to a constant value in the point shader. I'd suggest using `GL_POINTS` with the original shader (and passing **3** to `glDrawArrays (...)`) and seeing if that displays the 3 points individually.

Comment: They did have different vendors, but the results were the same on each computer, how would I define vertex attributes? I am unfamiliar with OpenGL. EDIT: I'll try what you just recommended EDIT2: the three points do not get rendered when I try what you stated.

Comment: A vertex attribute is defined either by calling `glVertexAttribPointer (...)` or simply `glVertexAttrib* (...)`. You need them to do any more complex rendering, and I think if you get far enough along in the OpenGL SuperBible you should be introduced to them shortly.

Comment: Since drawing points doesn't work with this code, is there a potential it's something wrong with how I define my array?

Comment: I fixed the issue, it seems it was completely unrelated to the GLSL or the vertex attributes, I was incorrectly linking the program.